# Map function doesn't map tasks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I'm currently learning React and I'm creating a to-do part of a MERN app, I made the task object from MongoDB into an array, and I'm trying to use the map function to make the tasks show up on screen.

My get request works, the array shows up on console, but nothing shows up on screen. When I console log the sunday.Task to try to get more information it says undefined.

I tried to mess around with the map function for two weeks using react docs, mdn javascript docs, different sites, and I have looked at other map questions on here and they don't seem to fit my use case. How could I edit this map function so tasks shows up on screen?

The JS for before return:

```
export default function Planner() {



 const [setSunday, setSundayTask] = useState({
   Task: "",

 });


 const [ sundays, setSundayEntry] = useState([]);


 const navigate = useNavigate();

 // These methods will update the state properties.
 function updatesetSunday(value) {
   return setSundayTask((prev) => {
     return { ...prev, ...value };
   });
 }

 // This function will handle the submission.
 async function onSubmitSunday(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // When a post request is sent to the create url, we'll add a new record to the database.
   const newSunday = { ...setSunday };

   await fetch("http://localhost:5000/sunday/add", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(newSunday),
   })
   .catch(error => {
     window.alert(error);
     return;
   });

   setSundayTask({ Task: ""});
   navigate("/planner");
 }


useEffect(() => {
  getSundayTask();
}, [sundays]);




 async function getSundayTask() {

  let sunday = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/sunday');

 
  
  console.log(sunday);

  setSundayEntry(sunday);
}



const sundaystodos = Object.keys(sundays);
```

JSX for returns:

```
     <div>
  <h1>Tasks:</h1>
  {sundaystodos.map((sunday, id) => {
  console.log(sunday.Task) 
    return (
      <li key={id}>
      {sunday.Task}
      </li>
    )})}
  
         </div>
```

Comment: how does sundaystodos look like after setting data? and whats the error you're getting in browser console?

Comment: @sid no errors in browser console, and sundaytodos.set.map((sunday, id) like that? It turns my react screen white, my apologies if that's not what you meant

Comment: `const sundaystodos = Object.keys(sundays);` you're using Object.keys() incorrectly here

Comment: @derFrosty how would I use it correctly? or do I have to use a different method to map my object?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look just at the map bit:

```
const sundaystodos = Object.keys(sundays);
...
{sundaystodos.map((sunday, id) => {
  ...
})}
```

`Object.key()` returns an array of strings. Always. It doesn't matter what the values are in the `sundays` object, only the **keys**, which are strings. So, when you use `map()`, your `sunday` variable will be a string, not an object with a Task field, e.g. `{ Task: 'a task' }`. If you want to get the value within the original object, you should use that key string (and I'd rename the variable from "sunday" to "key" to make that clear) you need to use `sundays[sunday]` (or `sundays[key]` if you rename the variable). For example, to list the task field, you will want `sundays[sunday].Task`

The logic above assumes that `sundays` is an object, e.g. `{ key: value }`, and not an array. If `sundays` is an array, then you cannot use `Object.keys()`.

Also, I'd recommend some new naming. There are too many "sunday" variables. E.g. I'd recommend using `sundaykeys` instead of `sundaytodos` and `sundaykeys.map(key =>`. Also, I'd use the standard naming for the "set" versions of your state variables, e.g. `const [sundays, setSundays] ...` and I would NOT use a "set" variable for the first state variable, and instead use `const [sunday, setSunday] ...`. Hope this helps you get on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for the help Daniel, it did. In the end it really was my variable names causing the issue. In messing around with renaming them I realized using data instead of sunday made the tasks display on screen on screen.